# Inserir dados com objetos relacionados

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou tentando inserir um objeto contendo que tem um relacionamento.

**Usuario** > **Empresa**

Primeiramente preciso obter os dados do *UsuarioId* na `View` de *Create* Estou fazendo da seguinte forma:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  var usuarioLogado = User.Identity.Name;
  var usuarioDb= new SelectList(db.Users.Where(u => u.Email == usuario), "Id", "Email");
  ViewBag.UsuarioId = UsuarioDb;
  return View();
}
```

E minha `View` que recebe:

```
 <div class="form-group formulario">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Usuario.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2",  })
        <div class="col-md-10">
           @* @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UsuarioId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled", @Value = ViewBag.UsuarioId } })*@
            @Html.DropDownList("UsuarioId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UsuarioId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Porém, ao enviar os dados pro meu `controller` `Post`:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "EmpresaId,UsuarioId,Nome,Cnpj")] Empresa empresa)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            empresa.EmpresaId = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.Empresa.Add(empresa);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.UsuarioId = new SelectList(db.Users, "Id", "Email", empresa.UsuarioId);
        return View(empresa);
    }
```

recebo o erro:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Empresas_dbo.AspNetUsers_UsuarioId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "PatrimonioContexto", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Qual é a forma correta para inserir os dados ?

Comment: Remova o disabled do `DropDownList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por padrão, elementos marcados com `disabled` não irão enviar valores pro server-side.

Seu erro diz

> *The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "[...]UsuarioId"*

Ou seja, ele não encontrou a *primary key* do valor utilizado em `empresa.UsuarioId`.

Para solucionar, você pode trocar o `disabled` por `readonly`.

```
@Html.DropDownList("UsuarioId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```